# Postgres: GROUP BY several column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have two table in this example.

( example column name )

First is the product

```
product_id | product_text
```

Second table is Price.

```
price_productid | price_datestart | price_price
```

Let's just say I have multiple datestart with the same product. How can I get the actual price ?

If I use GROUP BY in Postgres, with all the selected column, 2 row may come for the same product. Because the column price_datestart is different.

Example :

```
product_id : 1
product_text : "Apple Iphone"


price_productid : 1
price_datestart :"2013-10-01"
price_price :"99"


price_productid : 1
price_datestart :"2013-12-01"
price_price :"75"
```

If I try this :

```
SELECT price_productid,price_datestart,price_price,product_text,product_id
WHERE price_datestart > now()
GROUP BY price_productid,price_datestart,price_price,product_text,product_id
ORDER BY price_datestart ASC
```

It will give me a result, but two rows and I need one.

Comment: You need to use an aggregate function when you use group by.

Comment: I read that, but I am not familiar with.

Comment: Which row do you want?

Comment: You need to supply some more information.  What price are you expecting to obtain, given that both dates are in the future?

Comment: Sorry. Let's just say date is 2013-10-05. So, the price started on 2013-10-01. ( 99$ =

Comment: So you need `price_datestart <= now()` then, not `price_datestart > now()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `distinct on` syntax. If you want current price:

```
select distinct on (p.productid)
    p.productid, pr.product_text, p.price, p.datestart
from Price as p
    left outer join Product as pr on pr.productid = p.productid
where p.datestart <= now()
order by p.productid, p.datestart desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2f043/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems, but GROUP BY is not one of them.

First, although you have a datestart you don't have a dateend.  I'd change datestart to be a daterange, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE product
( 
  product_id int
 ,product_text text
);

CREATE TABLE price
(
  price_productid int
 ,price_daterange TSRANGE
 ,price_price     NUMERIC(10,2)
);
```

The `TSRANGE` allows you to set up validity of your price over a given range, for example:

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES(1, 'phone');
INSERT INTO price VALUES(1, '[2013-08-01 00:00:00,2013-10-01 00:00:00)', 199);
INSERT INTO price VALUES(1, '[2013-10-01 00:00:00,2013-12-01 00:00:00)', 99);
INSERT INTO price VALUES(1, '[2013-12-01 00:00:00,)', 75);
```

And that makes your `SELECT` much more simple, for example:

```
SELECT price_productid,price_daterange,price_price,product_text,product_id
FROM product, price
WHERE price_daterange @> now()::timestamp
AND product_id = price_productid
```

This also has the benefit of allowing you to query for any arbitrary time by swapping out `now()` for another date.

You should read up on ranges in PostgresQL as they are very powerful.  The example above is not complete in that it should also have indices on `price_daterange` to ensure that you do not have overlaps for any product.

[SQL fiddle with above solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/11756/3)

Comment: Of course I dont have a date_end ;) The price start one day... I don't know when it end ;) It just the "New price". But you're right With this information, query may be easier

Comment: Good use of ranges, but actually, in this task you don't need range - you can get most recent price easily with distinct on. Also, ig you would store ranges, you have to keep data consistent or you could have gaps

Comment: If you are keeping multiple prices for products at different times you really should keep track of when the price stops being valid.  Pulling it from the next/last row is inefficient and error-prone.  @Roman yes you need constraints but that's basic data hygiene, and the end result gives you lots of power to search for other info rather than just the current price.  Might not be necessary, though.

Comment: actually I'm using this types of query all the time, usually you don't need date when price stops being valid, you have you date, and you just need to get closest one price where `price_date <= date`. If you have proper indexes this very fast operation